# Some modifications for a display showing graphs of a function and its inverse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a display of the graphs of an exponential function and its inverse. I would like two slight modifications.

I do not want the line passing through (0,15) and (15,0) plotted.  I used `line width = 0pt` but that specification was ignored.  I use this line to place a point on the exponential function and a point on the logarithmic function.  I get "10 Bad Boxes."  Is the graph too wide?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5.5in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    xmin=-12,xmax=18,ymin=-12,ymax=17,
    axis lines=middle,
    restrict x to domain=-12:17,restrict y to domain=-12:17,
    enlargelimits,
    axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={fill=white},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

\addplot[dashed,line width=0.2pt,domain=-10:16,latex-latex,name path=reflection_line] {x} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=x$};
\addplot[domain=-10:16,line width=0pt,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
\addplot[green,domain=-10:4,samples=101,name path=an_exponential_function]  {pow(2,x)} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=2^x$};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^10:16,samples=101,name path=a_logarithm_function]  {log2(x)} node[fill=white, below=5pt] {$y=\log_2(x)$};

%The intersection of reflection_line and perpendicular_line is (5,5). The following commands
%label the point R and mark it with a point.
\coordinate (R) at (7.5,7.5);
\addplot[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {(7.5,7.5)};

\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and an_exponential_function,by={P}}];
\draw[fill,green] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and a_logarithm_function,by={Q}}];
\draw[fill,blue] (Q) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands put a brace above line segment PR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for P' and R' are defined to be 2.5pt from PR. A brace is drawn between P'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of PR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (P') at ($(P)!2.5pt!90:(R)$);
\coordinate (R') at ($(R)!2.5pt!-90:(P)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (P') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');

%These commands put a brace above line segment QR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for Q' are defined to be 2.5pt from QR. A brace is drawn between Q'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of QR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (Q') at ($(Q)!2.5pt!-90:(R)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}] (Q') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: line width=0pt is used to specify 1 pixel line width.  color=white works better.  opacity=0 is perfect.

Comment: @John Kormylo  The line `y = -x + 15` drawn using `line width=0pt` looks to be as thick as the line `y = x` drawn using no specification regarding line width.  (So, both lines appear to be drawn with a thickness of 0.4pt.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have several options here:

   - Use a white plot (this option I don't like much since the plot is still drawn but in white color):

     ```
     \addplot[white,domain=-10:16,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
     ```
   - Use a `\path` with the plot TikZ syntax which is not drawn:

     ```
     \path[name path=perpendicular_line] plot[domain=0:15] (\x,-\x + 15);
     ```
   - Add `draw=none` to the plot options:

     ```
     \addplot[draw=none,domain=-10:16,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
     ```
   - Use a path that is not drawn:

     ```
     \path[name path=perpendicular_line] 
       (axis cs:0,15) -- (axis cs:15,0);
     ```

   I'd prefer using any of the last two options.
2. Your code produces an overfull `\hbox` since the image is too wide for the default text area. You can prevent this by using the option `width=\textwidth`.

The complete example code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5.5in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    xmin=-12,xmax=18,ymin=-12,ymax=17,
    axis lines=middle,
    restrict x to domain=-12:17,restrict y to domain=-12:17,
    enlargelimits,
    axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={fill=white},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    width=\textwidth
    ]

\addplot[dashed,line width=0.2pt,domain=-10:16,latex-latex,name path=reflection_line] {x} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=x$};
%\addplot[draw=none,domain=-10:16,name path=perpendicular_line] {-x + 15};
\path[name path=perpendicular_line] 
  (axis cs:0,15) -- (axis cs:15,0);
\addplot[green,domain=-10:4,samples=101,name path=an_exponential_function]  {pow(2,x)} node[fill=white, above, right]{$y=2^x$};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^10:16,samples=101,name path=a_logarithm_function]  {log2(x)} node[fill=white, below=5pt] {$y=\log_2(x)$};

%The intersection of reflection_line and perpendicular_line is (5,5). The following commands
%label the point R and mark it with a point.
\coordinate (R) at (7.5,7.5);
\addplot[mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {(7.5,7.5)};

\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and an_exponential_function,by={P}}];
\draw[fill,green] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=perpendicular_line and a_logarithm_function,by={Q}}];
\draw[fill,blue] (Q) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands put a brace above line segment PR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for P' and R' are defined to be 2.5pt from PR. A brace is drawn between P'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of PR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (P') at ($(P)!2.5pt!90:(R)$);
\coordinate (R') at ($(R)!2.5pt!-90:(P)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (P') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');

%These commands put a brace above line segment QR and label the length `d`.
%First, coordinates for Q' are defined to be 2.5pt from QR. A brace is drawn between Q'
%and R'. In this way, the label for the length of QR is put in the center of the brace by
%default.
\coordinate (Q') at ($(Q)!2.5pt!-90:(R)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}] (Q') -- node[above right=3.5pt and 3.5pt,fill=white, inner sep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle{d}$} (R');
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]